# Riemann integrals: invariant under isometry?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be an [isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) and let $f:D\to\mathbb{R}$ be a [Riemann integrable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannIntegral.html) function on $D$, i.e. such that the limit $$\int_D f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,d x_1\ldots dx_n:=\lim_{\delta\to 0}\sum_i\bar{f}(\xi_{1,i},\ldots,\xi_{n,i})\Delta V_i$$ where $\xi_{k,i}$, $k=1,\ldots, n$ are arbitrarily chosen points in the $i$-th $n$-parallelepiped, whose volume is $\Delta V_i$, of the partition, whose mesh size is $\delta$, of a larger $n$-parallelepiped $P$ such that $D\subset P$, exists finite, independent from the partition and choice of $(\xi_{1,i},\ldots,\xi_{n,i})$; here $\bar{f}:P\to\mathbb{R}$ is the extension of $f$ such that $\forall\boldsymbol{x}\in D\quad\bar{f}(\boldsymbol{x})=f(\boldsymbol{x})$ and 
$\forall\boldsymbol{x}\in P\setminus D\quad\bar{f}(\boldsymbol{x})=0$.

I am intuitively inclined, in particular since integrals are often used in physics to define quantities that do not vary according to the choice of Cartesian coordinate system, to suppose that $$\int_D f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,d x_1\ldots dx_n=\int_{T(D)} (f\circ T^{-1})(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\,d x_1\ldots dx_n$$ but I am surprised to realise that I have not been able to prove it to myself. Is this equality valid and, if it is, how can it be proved? I have to remark that I have studied nothing yet of Lebesgue integration on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if $n\ge 2$ (I have only used Kolmogorov-Fomin's, which only covers the case $n=1$).

Comment: This is not a triviality.  The easy proof goes through Lebesgue integral: $f$ is Riemann integrable iff the set of discontinuities of $\overline{f}$ has Lebesgue measure zero; and in that case the Riemann integral agrees with the Lebesgue integral.   But I am assuming you want a proof not using Lebesgue measure.  I don't have a copy here, but as I recall there is a proof in T. Apostol, *Mathematical Analysis: A Modern Approach to Advanced Calculus* (1960)

Comment: For differentiable isometries (and the usual physics isometries, like rotation, translation, or even reflection are examples) this is a corollary of multivariate change of variables.